# TypeScript type of a package's module namespace, without importing it

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is it possible to get the TypeScript type of a package imported like so

```
import * as sdk from @sdk/example


type Sdk = typeof sdk; // <-- I need this
```

But without having to add `@sdk/example` to my dependencies, or at least without the need to import the entire package ?

Comment: `import * as sdk from ___` isn't importing the default export, it's importing a *module namespace object*, an object generated by the module system containing a property for each named export (and a `default` property for the default export, if any). The default export would be acquired via `import sdk from ___`.

Comment: TypeScript does some module gymnastics depending on your `tsconfig.json` settings (for instance, [`syntheticDefaultImports`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#allowSyntheticDefaultImports) and such), and those depend in part on what the module being imported is. So I think to help you with this, we'll need both your `tsconfig.json` and the actual name of the module. Otherwise, we can help if we assume a standard case, but that might miss edge cases because of the gymnastics.

Comment: In general, you can import just types without actually importing something in JS using [type imports](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/modules.html#typescript-specific-es-module-syntax) e.g. `import type sdk from "@sdk/example"` or `import type * as sdk from "@sdk/example"`. Does this help answer your question?

Comment: @mattlucock - I was thinking about that too, but for some reason I assumed (with no basis) it didn't work for module namespace imports. Seems to, though. Nice one!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - You can actually represent the type of an entire module even more flexibly as `typeof import("@sdk/example")`.

Comment: @mattlucock - Heh. :-) You have to unwrap the promise from it though. (Easily done.) Yeah, really no idea what I was thinking earlier.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder You actually don't. If you check what the return type of the JS function call `import("module")` is, it's `Promise<typeof import("module")>`. `import("module")` is actually special type syntax. Weird I know.

Comment: @mattlucock - Interesting! And yes, very weird, I'd expect `typeof import(___)` to be a `Promise<___>` type, since (as you say) that's what dynamic import always returns. Ah, well...

Comment: Thank you both for the clarifications, I edited the title. Once again, kind of a generic question, but if I import type only like you showed will it change anything on my app's bundle size ?

In my case, I am not actually using the @sdk/example but simply typing an argument to be able to inject it from another project.